# Using tcpdump On Growing Log Files

Tags: c, network-programming, gdb, tail, tcpdump

All,

I'm trying to debug a simple router where all of the packets going into it and sent out on the wire are logged in a tcpdump readable logfile.

Right now, I am doing a run of the program, stopping it, then using tcpdump to look at the packet log.

Is there anyway to get tcpdump to continously update itself as packets are added to the logfile? i.e. in a similar fashion to how tail works?

Ideally I'd like to run the program inside gdb, and then as packets are recv'd/sent, see them pop up in a stream given by tcpdump.

Edit: 
Right now the tcpdump command I'm using is

```
$tcpdump -r out.log -e -vvv- x
```

Comment: Maybe you should use [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) instead?

Comment: No Wireshark. I'm logged into a remote terminal and X-11 is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html):

```
-r  Read packets from file (which was created with the -w option).
    Standard input is used if file is ``-''.
```

so you can pipe the file into `tcpdump`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to do here. Could you give an example of the proper command to run?

Comment: Thinking further, perhaps there is some way to get tail to continuously print despite the fact there are no line returns in the pcap files?, Then you could run something like $tail -f out.log | tcpdump [options]. I couldn't figure out how to get tail to write stuff without '\n' characters.

Comment: Even easier - have your program write to a FIFO (`mkfifo(1)`) and have your `tcpdump` read from it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Not 100% shure if I grasp what you want, but is `tee` suitable?

I.e:

> sudo tcpdump '(udp and src port 53)' -nnvvXSs 1514 -l |  tee dump.log

*-l Make stdout line buffered*

---

If you'd like to hack in C, the [sniffex.c](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c) code can presumably be modified to meet your needs.

As a start change `filter_exp` to meet your needs.

Number of packages is set by `num_packets`, hard-coded to 10, used in `pcap_loop()`:

<sup>int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int  `cnt`, pcap_handler  callback, u_char * user);</sup>

    <sub>`cnt`Specifies the maximum number of packets to process before returning. A negative value causes the pcap_loop subroutine to loop forever, or until EOF is reached or an error occurs. A cnt of 0 processes all packets until an error occurs or EOF is reached.*</sub>

`argv[1]` is device to use.

---

Default output typically:

```
Packet number 2:
       From: 123.123.123.123
         To: 10.0.0.10
   Protocol: TCP
   Src port: 153
   Dst port: 53
   Payload (1440 bytes):
00000   de 15 be 61 60 47 9a 14  92 b0 5b 7c fa 64 51 4b    ...a`G....[|.dQK
00016   b0 b5 c4 4c b0 c2 a8 a3  89 60 10 36 29 7e 10 0c    ...L.....`.6)~..
00032   94 15 01 9a a5 29 26 0a  a9 a4 82 70 9f 22 ac 90    .....)&....p."..
...
```

Comment: Not really what I'm going for -- basically the executable I have will write out packets to a file, call it out.log, and I want to have tcpdump reading out of that file as more packets are added to it.